# Modify CKEditor Link feature similar to Gmail by removing pop-up

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I want to make CKEditor Link feature similar to Gmail 'Insert Link', so that when user click on that it will automatically convert text to link without asking for URL in popup.

Please advice.

Comment: did you tried to configure that using config.js

Comment: @himanshu yes I tried to customize config.js but found to customize the pop up only not to remove it. I want to remove the pop up and make it simple like Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple feature I would write a custom plugin.
What google insert link basically does is it checks if the string selected is a link (if it has a dot in basically. You can write some shenanigans like "gasgad.gsadfga" and it will automatically link it).
If it does not detect a link automatically it opens a dialog window.

If you don't know how to, check the CKEditor documentation on writing plugins (it's really simple) and you can use this code to get the dialog window function:

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'linkDialog', function ( editor ) {
    var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
    return {
        title: 'Insert link',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 100,

        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-basic',
                label: 'Basic Settings',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'link',
                        label: 'Link',
                        validate: CKEDITOR.dialog.validate.notEmpty( "Link field cannot be empty" )
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'text',
                        id: 'text',
                        label: 'Text (optional)',
                        'default' : selected_text
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        onOk: function() {
            var dialog = this;

            var link = editor.document.createElement( 'a' );
            link.setAttribute( 'href', dialog.getValueOf( 'tab-basic', 'link' ) );
            link.setAttribute( 'target','_blank' );
            if(dialog.getValueOf( 'tab-basic', 'link').substring(0, 8)=="https://" || dialog.getValueOf( 'tab-basic', 'link').substring(0, 7)=="http://")
            {
                link.setAttribute( 'href', dialog.getValueOf( 'tab-basic', 'link' ) );
            }
            else
            {
                link.setAttribute( 'href', "http://"+dialog.getValueOf( 'tab-basic', 'link' ) );
            }
            if(dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'text').length==0)
            {
                link.setText(dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'link'));
            }
            else
            {
                link.setText(dialog.getValueOf('tab-basic', 'text'));
            }

            editor.insertElement( link );
        }
    };
});
```

Now about the auto linking:
Just write a function if the selected text is a link before you show the dialog window:

```
var selected_text = editor.getSelection().getSelectedText();
if(selected_text.isLink) //this is where you would put your conditions if the text is indeed a link
{
//reuse the code from the dialog window for inserting the link element
}
else
{
//start the dialog window
}
```

Comment: In your ckeditor/plugins folder. You can find more info on how to create your own plugins here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_sample_1  The code I gave you is from a custom plugin I wrote (I tested it, it works).